# How to read records from last to top in stack?

Tags: c#

Below is my variable of type stack :

```
var records = Stack<Records>();
```

Suppose records contains data like below for eg:

```
3
2
1
5
8
```

Now I want to loop on this above variable but in reverse order like below:

```
foreach (var item in records)
{
  // item should have 8 then 5 then 1......
}
```

**Note :** I don't want to create overhead of converting this in to `IEnumerable` or `List` and then reverse loop.

Comment: Stacks are First In Last Out. You can only read them from top to bottom. You might want a queue which is First In First Out.

Comment: That's not how a stack works.  The "note" in your question suggests that you already know how to do this.  You either read the entire stack into another collection and reverse it, or don't use a stack in the first place.

Comment: Do you really want to use a stack? Or else you can use Queue class in C#.

Comment: You would end up with this overhead, the only question is if it is going to be in your code or in the library code. This is because `Stack<T>` has a specific purpose (LIFO container), and by iterating it in reverse order you are trying to work around this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Reverse()`:

```
foreach (var item in records.Reverse()) {
    ...
```

Additional info for OP:

> Stack is implemented as an array.
>
> Stacks and queues are useful when you need temporary storage for
>   information; that is, when you might want to discard an element after
>   retrieving its value. Use Queue if you need to access the
>   information in the same order that it is stored in the collection. Use
>   System.Collections.Generic.Stack if you need to access the
>   information in reverse order.

Comment: No suggestion of a `Queue<T>` instead of the stack?

Comment: records.Reverse() is converting this in to inenumerable?

Comment: @Tim, no suggestions. OP could use a `List` by the sound of it for this simple operation.

Comment: @Learning [Of course it does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497(v=vs.110).aspx) - there's no way around it if you want a `Stack<T>` (as opposed to some other container that allows enumeration in any order).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight All right sir.Thank you so much for the information.I thought there might be some way to read records in reverse order for stack and infact i search for this but couldnt find any answer related to this.Hence end up asking on SO :)

Comment: @Learning Why are you concerned with the efficiency of this? Is your stack larger than 5,000,000 items? Did you profile this, and saw that more than 10% of the time spent in your program is attributed to the section that reverses the stack? Of course you can hack your way to the array behind the stack collection, but I wouldn't do it even as a last resort, preferring to switch collection type instead.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Sorry for the late reply but i dont think so my stack will have items greater than 100-200 items so in that case does this records.Reverse() will have performance bottleneck?

Comment: This worked.Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this.Appreciated :)